# How to create a program that can rename an exe in program files and rename a folder in Windows registry

Tags: windows, batch-file, exe, rename, regedit

I'm new in this stuff! As far as I know when you install a program, the installer creates a folder in `C:\Program Files` with the contents of the application, and a folder appears in the windows registry with values it needs to work. I would like to create something like that that can rename an exe and rename a windows registry folder.

I already know how to rename an `.exe` with a `.bat` in the same folder:

```
@pushd "%~dp0" >nul 2>&1
@echo off
title Instalador
ren "Program1.exe" "Program2.exe"
@exit
```

And I tried using this line and opened regedit but idk how to change a folder's name with a command (for example renaming `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Program1` to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Program2`)

`C:\Windows\regedit.exe`

Comment: @Pieterjan as they are apparently not made of batch, what language are these commands for? Sorry for my ignorance

Comment: @Constanza C# for .NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no ***rename*** command in `regedit` command line. All you can do is copy it to new name and then remove old one:

```
@echo off
echo Copying Program1 to Program2
ren path\to\program1.exe path\to\program2.exe
reg copy HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Program1  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Program2 /s /f
reg delete HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Program1 /f
```

`/s` means Copies all subkeys and values

`/f` means Forces the operation without prompt.

Comment: that's for python, right? or is it possible to add it to the .bat?
Sorry for my ignorance, I just don't want to mess it up.

Comment: @Compo thank you very much for trying to keep things in order, but I wouldn't mind trying other options if people don't have solutions to do it in a batch :)

Comment: @Compo i dont know why its showed up in python if its really **not** tagged as python, anyway i have added batch script.

Comment: This site is for help with a single specific and reproducible issue with your submitted code, @Constanza, and that is batch file code. Change your tags, removing [[tag:batch-file]], and replacing it with [[tag:python]]., then add the python code you need help with. This site does not offer a free code writing service in a choice of languages. However, now you have an answer for a batch file, it is too late to do that.

Comment: @MND-Blow, there was a similar issue recently, where results were showing up when not tagged. I appreciate you having made the changes to keep this on topic. Thank you.

Comment: It may be worth noting that, because you are making changes to protected locations, that this batch file should be run elevated.